# How to execute terminal commands in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, bash, shell, terminal

I have an iOS app and in the unit tests (XCTests) I need to execute some terminal commands such as
`xcrun simctl shutdown [simulator-UDID]`

I created this function to run the shell scripts

```
func commandLine(launchPath: String, arguments: [String]) -> String {
    // Used to be NSTask() before Swift 3
    let process = Process()

    // Set the task parameters
    process.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
    process.arguments = ["pwd"]

    // Create a Pipe and make the process
    // put all the output there
    let pipe = Pipe()
    process.standardOutput = pipe

    // Launch the process
    process.launch()

    // Get the data
    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let output = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    print(output!)
}
```

However, I got the error saying that

> Use of unresolved identifier 'Process'

Did some research and it turns out `Process()` has been renamed to `CommandLine` in Swift 4, but changing to `CommandLine` causes different error

> 'CommandLine' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers

Comment: You cannot start processes in iOS.

Comment: Is there any other way to execute terminal commands before and after each unit test?

Comment: What about a pre-action (can be configured in the scheme editor) ?

Comment: Btw: Process was renamed to CommandLine, and NSTask was renamed to Process (from https://swiftweekly.github.io/issue-32/)

Comment: Thanks for the link. The pre-action runs before the scheme whereas I'm looking for a way to run before EACH unit test.

Comment: have anyone found the solution to this?