# Is Process always unresolved in iOS app or Playground?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, platform

In a iOS app, I want to use a file which have an following function using Process:

```
public func system(_ body: String) throws {
    if #available(macOS 10.0, *) {
        let process = Process()

        ...

    } else {
        fatalError()
    }
}
```

Then, I got a fallowing error even though I applied Availability Condition and I don't evoke this function:
Use of unresolved identifier 'Process'.

I tried a similar code in Playground, and I got the same error.

I learned we cannot use Process in iOS Apps with a regular way by this question: [How to execute terminal commands in Swift 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46592871/how-to-execute-terminal-commands-in-swift-4) , and I have a solution that I separate these codes with files by each using platforms. But I want to use this single file if I can.

Please give me your another solution for my ideal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if #available()` does a *runtime check* for OS versions.

```
if #available(macOS 10.0, *)
```

evaluates to `true` if the code is running on macOS 10.0 or later,
*or* on iOS/tvOS/watchOS with an OS which is at least the minimum deployment target.

What you want is a *conditional compilation,* depending on the platform:

```
#if os(macOS)
let process = Process()
#else
// ...
#endif
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution.
I am surprising the exist of Preprocessor macros in Swift.
I would like to master the macros, so could you tell me what document I should read?

Comment: @MatsumotoHarutaka: It is a “compilation directive,” not a preprocessor macro. You'll find it in https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Statements.html.

Answer (score 2):

Even though you already solved this problem, just for you to know, I want to tell you that actually, `Process()` (or `CommandLine()` in Swift 3.0 or newer) is available for iOS, but you'll need to use a [custom Objective-C header file](https://pastebin.com/V28wJq6A) which creates the object `Process()`/`CommandLine()`, or rather `NSTask()`, and everything it needs.

Then, in order to use this code with Swift, you'll need to create a [Bridging-Header](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_objective-c_into_swift), in which you'll need to import the `NSTask.h` file for it to be exposed to Swift and being able to use it in your Swift code.

Once done this, use `NSTask()` instead of `Process()`:

```
let process = NSTask() /* or NSTask.init() */
```

Or just use the following function in your code whenever you want to run a task:

```
func task(launchPath: String, arguments: String...) -> NSString {
    let task = NSTask.init()
    task?.setLaunchPath(launchPath)
    task?.arguments = arguments

    // Create a Pipe and make the task
    // put all the output there
    let pipe = Pipe()
    task?.standardOutput = pipe

    // Launch the task
    task?.launch()
    task?.waitUntilExit()

    // Get the data
    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let output = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

    return output!
}
```

As you can see, `NSTask()` would be the equivalent to `Process()` in this case.

And call it like this:

```
task(launchPath: "/usr/bin/echo", arguments: "Hello World")
```

This will also return the value, so you can even display it by doing:

```
print(task(launchPath: "/usr/bin/echo", arguments: "Hello, World!"))
```

Which will print:

```
~> Hello, World!
```

For this to work and not throwing an `NSInternalInconsistencyException`, you'll need to set the launchPath to the executable's full path instead to just the directory containing it.

You'll also need to set all the command arguments separated by ***commas***.

Tested on both iPad Mini 2 (*iOS 12.1 ~> Jailbroken*) and iPhone Xr (*iOS 12.2 ~> not jailbroken*).

**NOTE**: Even though this works both on non-jailbroken and jailbroken devices, your App will be rejected on the AppStore, as [@ClausJørgensen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95309/claus-j%C3%B8rgensen) said:

> You're using private APIs, so it'll be rejected on the App Store. Also, Xcode 11 has some new functionality that will trigger a build failure when using certain private APIs.

If your app is targeting jailbroken iOS devices and will be uploaded to a third-party store like Cydia, Zebra, Thunderbolt or Sileo, then this would work correctly.

Hope this helps you.